# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function LAST_INSERT_ID()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am inserting data in two tables on my database. and i used `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function

but i am getting this error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function LAST_INSERT_ID()

this is my code:

```
$sql = "";
$sql .= "BEGIN; ";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO circle_call_prefixes (";
$sql .= "  circle";
$sql .= " ,prefix";
$sql .= " ) VALUES (";
$sql .= "  :cid";
$sql .= " ,:prefix";
$sql  = "INSERT INTO circle_call_destinations (";
$sql .= "  autoNo";
$sql .= " ,destination";
$sql .= " ,source_circle";
$sql .= " ) VALUES (";
$sql .= LAST_INSERT_ID();
$sql .= " ,:prefix";
$sql .= " ,:prefix";
$sql .= " COMMIT; ";
$sql .= " );";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
foreach($Insert_array as $e1)
{
    $stmt->bindValue(':circle', $e1['cid']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':prefix', $e1['prefix']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':comment', $e1['comment']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':cid', $Cid);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

`LAST_INSERT_ID` is in SQL, try this:

```
$sql = "";
$sql .= "BEGIN; ";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO circle_call_prefixes (";
$sql .= "  circle";
$sql .= " ,prefix";
$sql .= " ) VALUES (";
$sql .= "  :cid";
$sql .= " ,:prefix";
$sql  = "INSERT INTO circle_call_destinations (";
$sql .= "  autoNo";
$sql .= " ,destination";
$sql .= " ,source_circle";
$sql .= " ) VALUES (";
$sql .= "LAST_INSERT_ID()";
$sql .= " ,:prefix";
$sql .= " ,:prefix";
$sql .= " COMMIT; ";
$sql .= " );";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

foreach($Insert_array as $e1){
              $stmt->bindValue(':circle', $e1['cid']);
              $stmt->bindValue(':prefix', $e1['prefix']);
              $stmt->bindValue(':comment', $e1['comment']);
              $stmt->bindValue(':cid', $Cid);
              $stmt->execute();
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is a function of Mysql, you've put it as PHP function, sometime using string append will cause this kind of issues, it's better to use string block as below.

```
$sql = <<<SQL
        BEGIN;
        INSERT INTO circle_call_prefixes(circle ,prefix)
        VALUES (:cid, :prefix);
        INSERT INTO circle_call_destinations(autoNo, destination, source_circle)
        VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), :prefix, :prefix);
        COMMIT;
SQL;
```